# Injeção de dependência, Angular

Tags: angular

Estou aprendendo Angular e travei um pouco nas injeções de dependência. No site diz que o decorador @Injectable() deve ter um provedor de serviço declarado. Algo mais ou menos assim:

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
Mas quando coloco isso a IDE acusa erro, dizendo que o decorador espera 0 argumentos e tem um presente, e o projeto não funciona. Como resolvo isso?

Comment: Talvez você não tenha declarado ele como provider no app.module

Answer (score 1):

So colocar

```
@Injectable() 
export class MeuService
```

e colocar o servico dentro dos providers em app.module

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { JokeModule } from './joke/joke.module';
import { MeuService } from './meuService.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule       
  ],
  providers: [ MeuService ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Colocando o serviço no app module ele sera um singleton pra toda a aplicação que na maioria dos casos e o comportamento desejado.